# for loop, if statement

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I'm really new to python. i'am trying to get this working.

```
import math
number, times = eval(input('Hello please enter the value and number of times to improve the guess followed by comma:'))
guess=number/2
sq_math= math.sqrt(number)
if times>1:
    for i in range(2,times+1):
        guess=(guess+times/guess)/2
        if round(guess,1) == round(sq_math,1):
         break

else:
    pass

print('Newtons method guessed {0}, square root was {1}'.format(guess, sq_math))
```

So what he best way? Thank you guys!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [ask] and help us help you by explaining what you want to happen, what errors you are hitting, and what you don't understand.

Comment: what does it do? whats it supposed to do? any errors? what output do you expect? what output do you get?

Comment: Please please please, don't do this: `number, times = eval(input(...))`

Answer (score 1):

You want to do the boolean not-equal comparison `round(guess,1) != round(sq_math,1)` in a separate `if` clause, just as you have done for the equality comparison `==`:

```
if times>1:
    # break this next line up in to two lines, `for` and `if`
    # for i in range(2,times+1) and round(guess,1) != round(sq_math,1): 
    for i in range(2,times+1):                  # for check
        if round(guess,1) != round(sq_math,1):  # if check
            guess=(guess+times/guess)/2
        if round(guess,1) == round(sq_math,1):
            break
        times-=1 #decrement times until we reach 0
```

Demo:

```
Hello please enter the value and number of times to improve the guess followed by comma:9,56
Newtons method guessed 3.0043528214, square root was 3.0
```

Comment: "Hello please enter the value and number of times to improve the guess followed by comma:9,56
Newtons method guessed 7.483314773547883, square root was 3.0" for some reason its don't want to give me right answer.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what the right answer is. What is the right answer you want to get? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45291577/for-loop-if-statement/45292363?noredirect=1#comment77545467_45291577

Comment: you can see in formula. when round(guess) will be 3 it should break and print guess.

Comment: It doesn't look like the `times` count is changing. Try adding `times-=1` at the end of the `for`-loop (see updated code in answer)

Comment: When I try `169, 100` I get an answer that's off by a factor of ten.  Ditto for many other numbers, 100, 144, etc.

Comment: I agree -- Sounds like a problem for the OP to fix, or perhaps your correct version addresses this and offers a more comprehensive solution, as was mentioned in the comments we do not know what math problem is needing to be solved. My answer only attempted to address the original question of "for loop, if statement".

Answer (score 0):

I believe the primary problem is this formula is incorrect:

```
guess = (guess + times / guess) / 2
```

it should be:

```
guess = (guess + number / guess) / 2
```

I don't see any problem with your `if` statement nor your `for` loop.  A complete solution:

```
import math

number = int(input('Please enter the value: '))
times = int(input('Please enter the number of times to improve the guess: '))

answer = math.sqrt(number)

guess = number / 2

if times > 1:
    for _ in range(times - 1):
        guess = (guess + number / guess) / 2
        if round(guess, 1) == round(answer, 1):
            break

print("Newton's method guessed {0}; square root was {1}".format(guess, answer))
```

USAGE

```
% python3 test.py
Please enter the value: 169
Please enter the number of times to improve the guess: 6
Newton's method guessed 13.001272448567825; square root was 13.0
%
```

Though I believe I'm really implementing the Babylonian method for finding square roots.